# How to run app on startup as different user?

Tags: debian, boot, daemon, minecraft

I have MineCraft server, and I need run it every time I start Debian.

I solved it, but it always run as root.

I need it run as normal user.

Answer (score 1):

Root is able to run anything as any user by using the command [`/bin/su`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?su)

You can use it like:

```
/bin/su -c userid /usr/bin/local/minecraftserver
```

Comment: Thank you verymuch !!!! It worked :) I am really happy its working, because i spent much time finding how to do it :( Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

A more robust solution to this would be to create a script to be added to init.d so that the server will be started on startup and properly shut down, should the server need to reboot or power off.  An excellent example of doing this is Pahimar's ForgeCraft script: https://github.com/pahimar/ForgeCraft-Script/blob/master/script/minecraft

This also includes functionality to do periodic backups (by having a cron job execute "service minecraft backup" and other useful things.

Additionally, you will be able to access the server console directly using screen.